# Otto Event Bus object post limit

Tags: android, event-bus, otto

Is there a limit of objects that can be posted to a single event bus? I want to post many user's texts onto an event bus, but I'm worried I'll somehow overload the Bus.

Comment: What if you create an object with attributes representing those users' texts and then post it?

Comment: What do you want to do with the texts? Maybe a priority queue is a better fit if you're going to send/deliver them.